# I'm Stuck with a simple lighttpd url.rewrite

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, lighttpd

Just switched from apache and having some rewrite issues.

Simple task: rewrite "http://www.foo.com/BAR/" to "http://www.foo.com/BAR/index.php"

I've tried the following (and variations) but it doesn't parse.

```
url.rewrite = (
   "/BAR/" => "/BAR/index.php"
)
```

I suck in regexps btw.

Comment: probably belongs to serverfault, just noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Forgot a "," to from a previous rewrite line...